# query to get the count per day

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Basically, I have two tables table1 and table2

These are the output's of these tables.

```
 This is the sample output of table1,
   ID        PDATE
   4    2013-04-16T17:47:49
   4    2013-04-16T17:36:40
   5    2013-04-16T17:58:23
   5    2013-04-16T17:37:47
   11   2013-04-17T17:51:28
   5    2013-04-17T18:10:28
   4    2013-04-17T18:10:14
   11   2013-04-17T17:39:11

 This is the sample output of table 2,
   ID          RDATE
    4   2013-04-16T17:42:58
    5   2013-04-16T17:55:22
    5   2013-04-19T17:31:07
    5   2013-04-19T17:16:03
    5   2013-04-19T17:00:50
    4   2013-04-19T17:06:34
    17  2013-04-19T17:57:32
```

I wanted to join these tables and get the output of no.of ID'S count per day with in a week.
Since the date columns in both the outputs are date+time (U can ignore time part, only consider date part)

My expected output should be,

```
    ID        COMBINEDDATE
     2         2013-04-16
     3         2013-04-17
     0         2013-04-18
     3         2013-04-19
```

The above output is based on the two tables output.

Note : if the same ID is present in both the tables with same time stamp (ignore time part)
consider this count as 1 even if multiple entries of the same id are present within the same day.

Comment: What is stopping you? Where do you have a problem doing what you want to do? You said you want to join the tables but perhaps you should consider a union of the tables instead? Try that and see what it leads to. Or you could show the query that does the job for only one table if the issue you have is that there are two tables.

Comment: If the result is supposed to reflect a JOIN between the two tables for the same ID on a given day (ignoring time), can you explain why you have a result of 3 for 4/17? Table 2 doesn't have a single row on that date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23e35/17)

Query:

```
  ;with 
  Datas(ID, PDate) as
   (
      select ID, cast(convert(varchar, PDate, 101) as datetime) PDate
      from TableA
      union all
      select ID, cast(convert(varchar, PDate, 101) as datetime) PDate
      from TableB
    ),
  Dates(PDate, MaxPDate) as
    (
      select min(PDate) PDate, max(PDate) MaxPDate
      from Datas
      union all
      select PDate + 1 PDate, MaxPDate
      from Dates
      where
        (PDate + 1) <= MaxPDate
    )
  select count(distinct ID), convert(varchar, Dates.PDate, 101) PDate
  from 
    Dates
    left join Datas on Dates.PDate = Datas.PDate
  group by Dates.PDate
  order by 2
```